# Understanding asset injection in GSPs

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I don't understand how are all the CSS and JS injected.

I find asset tags in main.gsp, but only for application.css and application.js

Nothing in the GSPs generated for the domain-classes.

But in the sources of the served pages I find them all:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap.css?compile=false" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/grails.css?compile=false" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main.css?compile=false" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/mobile.css?compile=false" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application.css?compile=false" />
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-2.2.0.min.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?compile=false" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/application.js?compile=false" ></script>
```

I red, that I can control them globally with includes and excludes.
Can I control them in main.gsp?
And where I'd decide them on a per page basis?

Thanks, Rawi

Comment: I can probably answer your question in regards to the asset-pipeline, but I'm not sure how it relates to domain classes.  What do you expect to see in a GSP from a domain class? Was the GSP in question created by you or generated by Grails?

Comment: Ashamed! I'd delete the question if I knew how. Better searching and reading educates! https://github.com/bertramdev/grails-asset-pipeline/wiki/Why-asset-pipeline-over-grails-resources-plugin. It's all about requires in application.css and .js. I thought that would be a comment block.